# MATLAB recursive function [Factorials]

Tags: function, matlab, recursion, factorial

The code works but I am confused. When `n==1`, I am assigning `a=1`, shouldn't that overwrite the value and return only 1?

```
format compact
fct(5)
```

---

```
function a = fct(n)
    if n==1
       a = 1; 
    else 
       a = n*fct(n-1);
    end
end
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Post your code as text into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I picture it... Below is a recursion/factorial diagram that shows the cascading effect of the recursive calls. At the deepest recursive call `fct(1)` is evaluated which is equal to 1 given by the first if statement. Each recursive call is therefore defined by a deeper recursive call. I typically like to decompose the recursive function until reaching its terminating case. I guess a way to phrase it is *"a function within function"* not so much of a loop.

[image: Recursive Process]

Where, `fct(1) → 1`

---

```
format compact
fct(5)

function a = fct(n)
    if n == 1
       a = 1;
    else
       a = n*fct(n-1);
       fprintf("%d\n",a);
    end

end
```

### Cumulative/Recursive Results:

```
2
6
24
120

ans =
   120
```

---

### My Preferred Structuring:

```
format compact
fct(5)

function a = fct(n)
    if n > 1
       a = n*fct(n-1);
    else
       a = n;
    end
end
```